UI not updated when changing locale (easy_localization)
Problem:
In my project I'm using flutter_bloc, go_router and easy_localization. When I'm changing the locale using context.setLocale(<locale>) the UI is not updated. But the state of my language cubit changes. The UI only updates, when I save the file. So what could be the problem here?
Package versions:
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.6
easy_localization: ^3.0.7
go_router: ^14.2.3

Example usage of translations
Text(LocaleKeys.hello.tr())

Easy Localization Config
  static const _translationAssets = 'assets/translations';

  AppLocalizationConfig({required super.child, super.key})
      : super(
          supportedLocales: AppLocale.supportedLocales,
          path: _translationAssets,
          fallbackLocale: AppLocale.de.locale,
          startLocale: AppLocale.de.locale,
          useFallbackTranslations: true,
          useOnlyLangCode: true,
          assetLoader: const CodegenLoader(),
        );
}

Code:
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _App();
}

class _App extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext superContext) {
    return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        appRouter.refresh();
      },
      child: AppLocalizationConfig(
        child: GlobalLoaderOverlay(
          child: FlutterSizer(
            builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {

              // this is always called when language changed
              final locale = context.watch<LanguageCubit>();

              return MaterialApp.router(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                routerConfig: appRouter,
                localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
                supportedLocales: AppLocale.supportedLocales,
                locale: locale.state.locale, // context.locale does also not work
                theme: context.read<ThemeBloc>().state.themeData,
                builder: BotToastInit(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```dart


Are you using context whenever you define language keys? if you don't use context, the UI won't automatically rebuild when you change the language.
For example, if you define the context like this:
Text(context.tr('title'))

The UI will rebuild. However, if you don't define the context, like in the example below, the UI won't rebuild:
Text('title').tr()


I am using the generated class LocaleKeys. For example: Text(LocaleKeys.hello.tr())

Could you try adding context inside tr(), like this: Text(LocaleKeys.hello.tr(context: context)), and see if it works?

Yes. by passing the context it works. But before I switched from AutoRoute to GoRouter, Text(context.tr('title')) had no problems. What could be the reason for that?

I don’t know the code before and after you started using GoRouter, but what’s certain is that for the translation to change, a rebuild is required. In this context, you need to use context to notify changes across all pages with 'context'.
